# How to call API request for each key of a JSON Object separately in REACT JS by loop?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, loops

I have **JSON Object** data stored in state of **mycart** in the following format:
(this is the data of products which are grouped by their **CompanyNames**)

```js
{
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "4500"

            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "2300"
            }
        ],

        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "1500"
            }
        ],
        

         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "234"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "999"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "288"
            }
        ]
    
}
```

Now I wanna place  separate orders for each Company. Like if Company A : **"Master Automotives"** has 2 products I wanna call API to place its order **separately**

and then call the API again for Company B: **"Repair Soltions"** which has 1 product and place its order. And so on for all the companies which are present in mycart JSON object.

I wanna loop through the **mycart** Object according to Company Names and call APIs **separately** for each Company in a same function. (This Object **mycart** can have multiple companies. dynamic).

This is how My API call will be. **I just dont know how to loop through my JSON Object within this function:**

```js
placeOrder()
{
      const orderData = {
      CustomerID: this.state.customer.CustomerID,
      TotalPrice: this.state.totalPrice } 
      //TotalPrice is each Company's items' total

    //nested API call
    axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/create_order.php', orderData)
      .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      this.setState({orderID: res.data.oid});
   
      const cartOrder = this.state.mycart;
      alert("Congratulations! Your Order is Confirmed");
      return axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/insert_order_details.php', cartOrder)
      .then((result) => {
          alert("Your all order items added to order details table");
      });
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var requestObj = {
    company1: [{
        name: "Prod1",
        qty: "12"
    }, {
        name: "Prod2",
        qty: "10"
    }],
    company2: [{
        name: "Prod3",
        qty: "11"
    }, {
        name: "Prod4",
        qty: "13"
    }],
    company3: [{
        name: "Prod5",
        qty: "1"
    }, {
        name: "Prod6",
        qty: "2"
    }, {
        name: "Prod7",
        qty: "3"
    }]
}

for(let companyName in requestObj){
    let orderData = requestObj[companyName];
    placeOrder(orderData);
}
```